# magento coupen redirect to home page?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, redirect

When I apply a coupon code on cart page and then submit it automatically, the customer is redirected to home page and show success message in home page only.

How to avoid the redirect, stay on the same page and show the success message on the cart page?

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" method="post">
    <div class="discount">
        <div class="discount-form">
           <input type="hidden" name="remove" id="remove-coupone" value="0" />
            <div class="input-box">
                <input class="input-text" id="coupon_code" name="coupon_code" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getCouponCode()) ?>" placeholder="Enter Your Coupen code if you have...." />
            </div>
            <div class="buttons-set">
                <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?>" class="button" onclick="discountForm.submit(false)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Apply Coupon') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php if(strlen($this->getCouponCode())): ?>
                    &nbsp; <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?>" class="button" onclick="discountForm.submit(true)" value="<?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Cancel Coupon') ?></span></span></button>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var discountForm = new VarienForm('discount-coupon-form');
discountForm.submit = function (isRemove) {
    if (isRemove) {
        $('coupon_code').removeClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "1";
    } else {
        $('coupon_code').addClassName('required-entry');
        $('remove-coupone').value = "0";
    }
    return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(discountForm)();
}
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Status messages normally are handled by your page design. Look at app/design/frontend/base/default/template/1column.phtml and find  `$this->getChildHtml('global_messages')`. But even if there is none, your redirect to the homepage is not normal. Can you give more info please. Are you using a commercial template? Please post the complete HTML form-node of the coupon input field.

Comment: check my update question

Comment: sucess message redirect to homepage

Comment: @Magento2 May i know what change you did?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the redirect, correct?

The coupon code is processed here: `\Mage_Checkout_CartController::couponPostAction`, as you can see in your form:

```
<form ... action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart/couponPost') ?>" ... >
```

As far as I can see every path ends with `\Mage_Checkout_CartController::_goBack`

```
protected function _goBack()
{
    $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
    if ($returnUrl) {

        if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
            throw new Mage_Exception('External urls redirect to "' . $returnUrl . '" denied!');
        }

        $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
    } elseif (!Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart')
        && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')
        && $backUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl()
    ) {
        $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
    } else {
        if (($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'add') && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')) {
            $this->_getSession()->setContinueShoppingUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
        }
        $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
    }
    return $this;
}
```

I neither can see a param `return_url`, nor `in_cart`.

So you should be redirected to the cart.

Whatever happens, you have a module which kills this behaviour and we can't help you debug this. Read [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store) and turn on your xdebug to check where your code is running.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is solved by adding https url, in the action of the form in which my coupon code input field is present.There was http url in the action of the from that was redirecting to http url (unsecure) home page.